# Save comma separated attribute as new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have 3 models in my rails app: Products, Categories and CategoriesProducts(join between products and categories). In my products form, i am accepting nested attributes for categories. The user is able to enter multiple categories separated by commas. How do I correctly save each category as a record in my categories table?

Comment: This railscast shows an exact solution for that. [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes).

Comment: You might be interested in something like a token field -> [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised) (If you don't have a railscast subscription see the old [one](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields)) instead, it works in the same way the tags work for a SO question.